# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext

Tags: web-services, jsp, java-metro-framework

I have 3 Webservices which is created with netbean 6.9

when I working on my computer at work, it run smoothly with no error. However, When I copy the netbean project to my computer at home, it run with error which look like this.

```
 SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:166)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:338)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:201)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:505)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:253)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.java:147)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:124)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
        at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:378)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at java.lang.StackTraceElement
                at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
                at java.lang.Throwable
                at public java.lang.Throwable[] com.factbook.webservice.jaxws.ExceptionBean.suppressed
                at com.factbook.webservice.jaxws.ExceptionBean

        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:153)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
        this problem is related to the following location:
                at java.lang.StackTraceElement
                at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
                at java.lang.Throwable
                at public java.lang.Throwable[] com.factbook.webservice.jaxws.ExceptionBean.suppressed
                at com.factbook.webservice.jaxws.ExceptionBean

        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.api.JAXBRIContext.newInstance(JAXBRIContext.java:106)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.developer.JAXBContextFactory$1.createJAXBContext(JAXBContextFactory.java:109)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:161)
        at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl$1.run(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:154)
        ... 32 more
```

Comment: Same environment at home (e.g. JDK, Netbeas, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem on Java 7 (Java 1.7). Resolved it by removing webservices-api-2.0.1.jar from the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

This URL has more in-depth explanation of the root cause of this exception

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4754

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, there is a conflict in the version of the webservices jar that the application is expecting and what has been loaded by the classloader. We had a similar issue where the application would work in Tomcat but give an error in Weblogic

We ended up creating a weblogic.xml in the WEB-INF folder of the war with the following in container-descriptor

```
**<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>javax.xml.ws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.ws</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>**
```

As you can see we are requesting weblogic to honor the webservices packages that come with the application and ignore the weblogic version of webservices packages

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but i just had to remove the exceptions, cause i was throwing a not generic exceptions like JAXBException, then create a EndPoint that Return a custom Exception something like this:

```
@WebService
public class MyEndPoint {




    @WebMethod
    public String myOperation(String xmlString) throws MyException {
        ...
        return null;
    }



}
```

And my Exception class like this:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return super.getMessage();
    }

    public MyException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

In my service interface Implements, i catch all the Specifics Exception and throw a MyException to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic exception; *"Unable to create JAXBContext"*

JAXB error is produced while converting Java objects to XML or vice a versa if there is something wrong on mapping.

> method **mesajUzunlu*ğ*u()** produce a client contains methods and a wrong
>   mapping. Beside this **tempuri.org** targetNamespace totally ruin other
>   services using this namespace.
>   @("mesajUzunl**u\u011f**u") this string in ğ unicode representation doesn't match with **ğ** and we cat Unable to create JAXBContext error

[ServiceWSDL_URL_mesajUzunlu**ğ**u][1]

I got this error because in my mapping there is a non ASCII character. **'ğ'** . 
Unfortunately, even serious providers provide web services which use http://tempuri.org as namespace. The right thing to do is using service endpoint URL. Anyway. This produce **`org.tempuri`** package for Web client proxy classes. When there are more than one tempuri.org using web service providers exist and you produce your class accordingly your jar will be compiled towards org.tempuri for more than one service. Then what happens ? Even this non-ascii character occurs only for a particular service , all my clients started to give this error surprisingly. I've just discovered real cause by investigating Call Stack very carefully. I do not understand why these serious organizations such as Ministries or Telecommunication firms use tempuri.org.

My advice is looking for non-ASCII chars ,following StackTrace carefully and considering org.tempuri while coding clients.

Environment: Java 1.7, no webservices-api-2.0.1.jar , latest jaxb-imp.jar

> **JAXB** stands for Java architecture for XML binding.It is used to
>   convert XML to java object and java object to XML.JAXB defines an API
>   for reading and writing Java objects to and from XML documents.Unlike
>   SAX and DOM,we don't need to be aware of XML parsing techniques

For this particular case in this question ,the statement above led us to understand following stackTrace element,there is an error can't be transfered to us.Because of Object<-->XML serialization.

> java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default
>   constructor.

Only thing to do is going through familiar stacktrace elements and using Soap UI kind of tools to investigate. If we are the owner of service it's better to return serialize-OK elements such as a JSON string or a custom XML mapped element.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception. My service classes were generated by CXF and when I call a service method it was saying "*28 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions*".  Because the service had 14 methods and 2 wrapper classes for each (`responseWrapper`, `requestWrapper`). 
The problem was that my project do not have `Cxf` library reference. Just add these (I used version 2.7.5) :

```
org.apache.cxf -> 
cxf-api,
cxf-tools-common,
cxf-rt-bindings-soap
```

Answer (score 0):

If your classes are used by another project, alter your classes to implement java.io.Serializable. This solved my problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a very old question with an accepted answer. It seems unlikely to me that an application that works in one environment but not another would be fixed by implementing java.io.Serializable.

Answer (score -2):

For a different Java project, after upgrading to Java 7, I also experienced

> error: [core] java.lang.StackTraceElement: A TypeDefinition must have a no-arg constructor or be annotated with a factory method.

which turned out to be a problem with enunciate. The solution was to replace all enunciate version numbers 1.25 by 1.26 in the respective pom.xml files.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.